# how to store exact one byte in a variable and output the same

Tags: c++

Reading through c++ document . I found char or unsigned char stores a byte.
However as in below code. If I wish to store 1 or any numbers or characters as it is.

```
 char c = 1; 
 std::cout << c; // it gives smiley  symbol.
 std::cout << int(c); // now gives desired output.
```

Now if I have a string and want to append char to string , I do,

```
 std::string bla = "hello"; 
 bla.push_back(c); // this appends the smiley symbol not 1. 
 bla.push_back(int(c)); // still appends the smiley symbol.
 bla.push_back(int(c -'0')); // appends D.
```

I wish to append exact 8 bit as it is in a string . Any suggestion

Comment: If you want to output 1 use quotes : `char c = '1';`

Comment: Which one is string? C is a character here. And character is one byte.

Comment: I have to store characters from a file to a vector of exact 8 bit characters. It seems possible through Qt. I have no idea while reading through a file it is stored as you said.

Answer (score 0):

`1` is a character literal in the ASCII table. `1` is not the same as `'1'`. Wrap the `char` around quotes to print out `1`. `char c = '1';`

Comment: Lets make a function to store any character or numbers then suppose 1 is entered through keyboard and 1 has to be stored in exact 8 bit variable. I have option using char and unsigned char. But result would be different while appending to a string This is my problem.

Comment: In the [ASCII table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), 1 is SOH, an unprintable character. The question asker is probably using [CP437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) for the terminal code page. `locale` (Linux) or `chcp` (Windows) would say.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the quote. Make the declaration char c = '1';

It will solve your problem.

Comment: I cannot store in an a single quote while reading through a file . It is stored as it is.